# Routing events by the event object type

Tags: c#, cqrs

What's the best way to route events to event handlers within a class, hopefully without needing to manually wire them up.

In the code sample below, events are being routed to the correct handler simply by casting the event to `dynamic`.

```
class Program {        
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var myEvent1 = new MyEvent1() as object;
        var myEvent2 = new MyEvent2() as object;
        var myObject = new Inherited() as Base;
        myObject.On(myEvent1);
        myObject.On(myEvent2);
    }
}

public class MyEvent1 {
}
public class MyEvent2 {
}

public class Base {
    public void On(object @event) {
        On((dynamic)@event);
    }
    public void On(MyEvent1 @event) {
        // it works!
    }
    public void On(MyEvent2 @event) {
        // it works!
    }
}

public class Inherited : Base {
}
```

However, when I move the typed event handlers to the inherited class, the handlers don't work anymore:

```
class Program {        
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var myEvent1 = new MyEvent1() as object;
        var myEvent2 = new MyEvent2() as object;
        var myObject = new Inherited() as Base;
        myObject.On(myEvent1);
        myObject.On(myEvent2);
    }
}

public class MyEvent1 {
}
public class MyEvent2 {
}

public class Base {
    public void On(object @event) {
        On((dynamic)@event);
        // stack overflow happens here :(
    }
}

public class Inherited : Base {
    public void On(MyEvent1 @event) {
        // nothing happens :(
    }
    public void On(MyEvent2 @event) {
        // nothing happens :(
    }
}
```

Obviously, it needs to work with handlers in the inherited class (and I have to work with `myObject` as an instance of the base class), so I have figure out a better way to route the events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
((dynamic)this).On((dynamic)e);
```

Comment: Insane genius! Thank you so much

Comment: I have been looking at the generated code using ILSpy and there seems to be quite a bit of compiler generated code replacing a `dynamic` cast. Basic issue was that compiler generated code is referring to the class directly, ignoring inheritance: (Pseudo example of the generated code) `Binder.InvokeMember("On", typeof(Base), new [] {...});` ..so first casting to the instance type `this` solving that issue

Comment: Thanks Maxwell for digging into ILSpy ... So reflection is being performed on on each event, substituting cpu cycles for developer time. This system will be running on Orleans in an auto-scaling cloud cluster with CQRS design principles - I'm excited to find out how it's going to work out.